# C++ template programming - Deferred function calls

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I am looking for an elegant solution to the following problem. I have a task struct that I use for deferred function calls.

```
template <typename T> struct Task1
{
    T Arg1;
    Delegate<T> TaskDelegate;
};
```

The problem I'm having is this:

```
Task1<const Foo&> MyTask;
```

This will result in the parameter being held as a const reference. Does anyone know a nice solution to get round this? I could enforce rules such as the delegate signature always taking const& params but this seems restrictive. I could always have two task structs (one for ref and one for value) but this seems nasty.

The other solution would be to create the following:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Task1
{
    T2 Arg1;
    Delegate<T1> TaskDelegate;
};
```

Is there anyway to default T2 to be the same type as T1? That way whenever I have a method value signature I don't need to have the additional template params.

EDIT:
The template is used for a multithreaded task scheduler. Here is an example:

```
void MyClass::Populate(const std::string& instrText);

CTaskScheduler::Schedule(Task1<const std::string&>(this, &MyClass::Popluate, "MyString"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem yet.  Could you give an example of how this template is actually used, and why the const ref is an issue?

Comment: if you want to remove reference, use `std::remove_reference<T>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take a look at the implementation of `function<>` either in boost or the upcoming standard. As a matter of fact, you can just *use* `function<>`. I think that the solution there was (before C++0x) to always store a copy of the arguments, if the user wants *reference semantics* they can use a *reference wrapper*.

As to how to get to a value, you can take a look at some simple metafunction to remove `const` or `&`:

```
// Remove reference:
template <typename T>
struct remove_reference {
   typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
struct remove_reference<T&> {
   typedef T type;
};
```

Similarly for `const`.

Comment: This is nice, because you don't have tu use the full type traits library from boost to implement this easy and small template.

Comment: I am actually using the FastDelegate library for my functions throughout the engine so I would prefer not to use both FastDelegate and boost::function. However the small template looks appealing

Comment: If your compiler supports either TR1 or C++11, there is a std::remove_reference<T> that does this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [boost.type_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) library to remove the const-ness of the parameter using `boost::remove_const`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to boost::type_traits, there is a [boos::call_traits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) specifically built to handle problems like this.  It also provides mechanisms to avoid the references of references problem.

Answer (score 1):

[boost::remove_const](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_const.html) should help you in this case:

```
template <typename T> struct Task1
{
    typename boost::remove_const<T>::type Arg1;
    Delegate<T> TaskDelegate;
};
```

Alternatively, you can avoid using boost if you use template specialization for const types:

```
template <typename T> struct Task1
{
    T Arg1;
    Delegate<T> TaskDelegate;
};

template <typename T> struct Task1<const T>
{
    T Arg1;
    Delegate<const T> TaskDelegate;
};
```

(Warning: untested)

Comment: The problem is I have more than one task implementation each taking more parameters which would lead to infinite template specializations depending on which parameters had the const refs

Comment: In this case, what I think you should do is to declare all the `function<>`s you're going to need, depending on the task's signatures.

Comment: I think that second should have been `template <> struct Task1<const T>`